# VSCode Debuging GCC Condition breakpoint with string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, conditional-statements, breakpoints

VSCode!! How i can set condition for breakpoinr like v.compare("2") == 0, thought interface. i use this
C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.

breakpoint is not active

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTqzQ.png)

in GDB directly is working

> (gdb) condition 1 v.compare("2") == 0 (gdb) i b Num     Type
> Disp Enb Address            What 1       breakpoint     keep y
> 0x000000000000166e in tttt(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, bool)
> at /home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp:53
> stop only if v.compare("2") == 0 (gdb)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup `gdb` as a debugging back-end in VSCode:

- you left-click left of the line number to set up a breakpoint
- a red dot appears
- you right-click the red dot and select `Edit breakpoint` and you will be able to specify an expression, select number of hits or transform the breakpoint into a tracepoint.

Comment: i know it ... but it is not works with string . look attached picture

Comment: can you print this expression in the vscode debugger console?

Comment: Expression for BP looks like v.compare("2") == 0. string in state.vscdb.backup  looks like INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES('debug.breakpoint','[{"enabled":true,"condition":"v.compare(\"2\") == 0","uri":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"/home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp","externa
l":"file:///home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp","path":"/home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp","scheme":"file"},"lineNumber":54}]');

Comment: Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
-exec i b
No breakpoints or watchpoints.

Comment: Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)

Breakpoint 2, main (ac=1, av=0x7fffffffdbc8) at /home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp:59
59   tttt("1", true);
-exec i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x00005555555556b8 in main(int, char**) at /home/butiaev/project/experience/vecxsdeq/project/executable/vecxsdeq.cpp:59
 breakpoint already hit 1 time

Comment: What happens when you try to print the expression itself? Can the debugger call `v.compare`?

Comment: when i use gdb directly it is works properly

Comment: i think it is defect in c++ plugin

Comment: for simple type is working Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000555555554cb7 in bp_bool(bool) at /home/butiaev/project/experience/bpcond/project/executable/bpcond.cpp:5
 stop only if v == true
3       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000555555554cec in bp_int(int) at /home/butiaev/project/experience/bpcond/project/executable/bpcond.cpp:10
 stop only if v == 10

Comment: [sources is](https://github.com/alekseibutiaev/experience/blob/master/bpcond/project/executable/bpcond.cpp)

Comment: [created an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8684)